# SQL Views vs. MS Access queries --- Updating data affects multiple base tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, ms-access, sql-view

I'm interested in understanding more about using a SQL View vs. a local query in MS Access. I like the fact that a view is basically a query that is stored on the server, and local machines running Access "see" it as a table.

Due to performance reasons, I'll sometimes take a view over a query since it typically makes a form load a lot faster. However, I've run into issues where I can't update the view if I make changes in two different fields that are in different base tables. Even if the view is constructed correctly with the correct joins, etc.

Just wondering if there is a more efficient and proper way to construct a query that can be updated.

Comment: Can you run the update through a stored procedure?  That is the most secure way to update data in SQL Server from Access.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg I'm not familiar with using a stored procedure via Access but I'd be very interested. Anything you recommend? I actually bind the View to a form in MS Access and then users make changes by updating the text boxes on the form if that makes sense.

Comment: I'd set it up to populate the form via a stored procedure (or multiple procedures, one for each applicable control), then when they make a change send the new values up to SQL via a stored procedure that takes those values as parameters.  This allows you to control exactly what data can be changed, which is important since Access is pretty weak on security.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Would you happen to have an example of this you can point me to?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg JET/ACE can be weak on security in that it has no user level security. But OP is not connecting to ACE/JET, they are connecting to Sql Server which has extremely strong user level security. So I'm not sure what you're implying is totally correct. Writing store procedures to do data editing seems a little overkill when you have a form with data validation that will submit the data for you.

Comment: Maybe I didn't specify well enough.. With my application I use Access simply as a front-end for forms and reports. For simple queries I can get away with local Access queries. But with more advanced queries (such as multiple tables that contain numerous records) I prefer to use a SQL View for performance reasons since a local Access query can really bog down. But then I can't update a View when the update affects multiple base tables. I'm really interested in learning best practice for the most optimized data source and the proper way to update them. Hope this makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm also using bound Access forms to allow users to interact with the data.

Comment: @Brad I guess my question would really be: What is the most efficient way to construct a datasource for a query that needs to be both 1) updateable and 2) efficient enough when dealing with multiple tables that have thousands of records in them.

Answer (score 0):

A user can never update more than one table at a time. That's a given. You need to construct your form (probably using subforms) to represent the data using either single table views, simple views that are updatable, or tables.

Subforms are basically left joins to the parent form. like

```
SELECT * 
FROM ParentForm P
LEFT JOIN SubForm S
 ON P.ParentID   <~~Link Master Field
    = S.ParentID <~~Link Child Field
```

So you can recreate your view using subforms.

If your view is too complicated to fit this mold it is probably not updatable and it probably means that the data you DO want to update are in a single table but all the rest of the info in your view are supporting information. i.e. displayed to support the user making a decision.

In this case you should make the `Record Source` of your form be the table/view (which is updatable) that you want to update. Then in comboboxes/listboxes/controls which support the data going into your updatable table/view you make the `Row Source` that of your complicated view.

No matter where the view is (in Access or on the server) if it is constructed in such a way that it is impossible to determine which record in which table should be changed, nothing else matters. YOu need to design the whole form differently.

Comment: @mntyguy ok, well in that case maybe you can expand your question with the query (or a representative version of it), how your forms are set up, and how you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Overall I do follow these guidelines and I understand all this. By "more complicated" I basically meant the number of records/table being queried, not the joins or design itself. I prefer the view over the query because it's faster. So why would a user be able to make changes to multiple changes with an Access query? Is that because Access has these tables indexed and knows how to make consistent updates based on primary keys, etc.?

Comment: Here's an example: Basically I have a form bound to a query (or view) that links a table called CONTACT_LOCATION (basically contains fields related to a person at a specific location) and a table called CONTACT (contact specific information such as first name, last name, etc.) So if a user updates the first name of a contact in the CONTACT table, and then makes a change to a field in the CONTACT_LOCATION table, this gets rejected due to the reasons you specified. So this is a case where a subform might not be appropriate. I might be wrong though.

Comment: The CONTACT_LOCATION table is used for the many-to-many relationship between LOCATION and CONTACT if that makes sense. (A contact can be at many locations and a location can have many contacts.) On my Contact form I want to show and allow viewing/editing of the contact specific information, while also allowing viewing/editing of information for that person at that location such as their title, level of interest, etc. Let me know if this doesn't make sense. Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that an Access Query has any special power over a SQL Server view. I think if you make one that is not updateable then the same view in the other system will still be not updatable.

Comment: For a many to many construction you can make your parent form be `CONTACT` the the subform be `CONTACT_LOCATION`, join on `ContactID`, then put a combobox on the subform that looks up locations in `LOCATION` that uses `LocationID` as the bound column. This will let view all the locations for a contact and be able to map new locations to them. To view the reverse relationship (all the contacts at a location) you'll need to reverse the whole set up. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54749/discussion-between-mntyguy-and-brad).